# Why Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox )?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

While creating push notifications certificate, I can see two options:

**Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)**

**Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production).**

If I can use *Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)* for both production and staging environments. Why do I need *Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)* certificate? Why still I require this option?

I have another question related to this. I'm delightful if anyone answers it.

Is creating push notifications certificate from **APP IDs Configurable Section** and **Certificates Section** same? (If it's same, creating production push certificate from APP IDs section will create  **Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)** or **Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production)** only?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose you want to test sending batch notifications from your external server to APNS. Which certificate would you like to test it on? Remember you don't want your live users to receive multiple test push notifications.

Also, lets suppose you want to test some third party server functionality of sending test notifications but you are still not in contract with them. Do you want to provide your Production certificate to them?

Comment: Got it. Love to hear answer for second question